# Not getting user data with google login

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have made a Google login with OAuth2.

The scope which I have used is userinfo. But I'm getting only the id from the object return.

I should get something like this:

```
{
 "id": "<some-id>,
 "email": "<correct-email-id>",
 "verified_email": true,
 "name": "blabla",
 "given_name": "blabla",
 "family_name": "blabla",
 "link": "<link>",
 "gender": "male",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

But I only get :

```
{
 "id": "<some-id>
}
```

I've tried:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=<access-token>
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=<access-token>
```

and this is the call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + accesstoken,
            async: false,
            contentType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
              profileemail = result.email;
              console.log(result);  
            },
            error: function(e) {
              console.log(e);
            }
          });
```

Comment: Can you specify the full string of the scope you have used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you request the **profile** scope. See:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtaininguserprofileinformation